# GitLab CI: `$CI_JOB_LOG` pass job log to another job

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

According to [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) there is `$CI_JOB_STATUS` env var that can be used as

> The status of the job as each runner stage is executed. Use with `after_script`. Can be success, failed, or canceled.

I am using it as

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - publish

.artifacts-template: &artifacts
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 weeks
    when: always
    paths:
      - bus

.test-template: &test
  stage: test
  needs: ["build"]
  allow_failure: true
  after_script:
    - echo $CI_JOB_STATUS > bus/$CI_JOB_NAME/status
  <<: *artifacts

#...
```

And that works really well.
My test jobs dump their statuses into artifacts within `after_script` step. Then publish job publishes those statuses into the website.

---

I would like to extend this workflow to include logs from those test jobs as well.

Therefore, in my `after_script` step, I would like to use something like

```bash
echo $CI_JOB_LOG > bus/$CI_JOB_NAME/log
```

or

```bash
cp $CI_JOB_LOG_PATH bus/$CI_JOB_NAME/log
```

What's the proper way to acquire logs of a job, so it can be dumped into file and re-used in the next stage job in the same pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the task of passing the job log to another job in GitLab CI, you will need to use a workaround: I do not think there is not a direct environment variable like `$CI_JOB_LOG` that holds the job's log.

Instead, try in the [`script` section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html) of your job to redirect the output of your commands to a file. You will need to do this for each command whose output you want to capture.
Define this log file as [an artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_artifacts.html), so it can be passed to subsequent jobs. In the subsequent jobs, you can access this log file as it is passed along as an artifact.

Your `.gitlab-ci.yml` would then be:

```yaml
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - publish

.artifacts-template: &artifacts
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 2 weeks
    when: always
    paths:
      - bus

.capture-log: &capture_log
  script:
    - command1 | tee -a job.log # Replace 'command1' with your actual command
    - command2 | tee -a job.log # Same for 'command2', and so on
    - ...
    - mkdir -p bus/$CI_JOB_NAME
    - echo $CI_JOB_STATUS > bus/$CI_JOB_NAME/status
    - mv job.log bus/$CI_JOB_NAME/log
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - bus/

.test-template: &test
  stage: test
  needs: ["build"]
  allow_failure: true
  <<: *capture_log
  <<: *artifacts

# Define your jobs using templates
```

The `script:` section is modified to include commands that capture the output and append it to `job.log`. And the `job.log` is then moved to the `bus/$CI_JOB_NAME` directory along with the job status file.
The `artifacts:` section makes sure both the status and log files are available to subsequent jobs.

Note: that approach does not capture system-generated logs (like those produced automatically by GitLab CI). Capturing these would require a feature that GitLab CI does not currently support natively. However, for most use cases, capturing the output of your script commands could be enough.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround, definitely more elegant than solution proposed by Vonc.

I am dumping job ID with `echo $CI_JOB_ID > bus/$CI_JOB_NAME/id`

```yaml
.test-template: &test
  stage: test
  needs: ["build"]
  allow_failure: true
  after_script:
    - echo $CI_JOB_STATUS > bus/$CI_JOB_NAME/status
    - echo $CI_JOB_ID > bus/$CI_JOB_NAME/id
  <<: *artifacts
```

and then in publish stage I use stored job ID to download raw logs via standard public url

```
curl -L "https://gitlab.com/namespace/project/-/jobs/${ID}/raw" -o log
```

As long as publish stage "needs" the previous test stage then all logs should be already available for download.

Please comment if you think that it is not safe.